# Inserting Json TEXT data with NHibernate CreateQuery

Tags: c#, sql, json, nhibernate, sybase

I need to save a serialized Json string of varying length to a TEXT column in a Sybase database.

Due to the datatype being TEXT, I cannot use a stored procedure.

NHibernate's CreateQuery seems like it will work BUT the single quotation marks in the Json string is breaking the Query.

As a last resort, I'm considering calling Replace on the single quotation marks and replacing it with a different symbol and then doing the reverse (Restoring the quotes) on the other end before decoding the data.

Is there a better way of achieving what I need to do?

Comment: Note that you can not do string manipulation on TEXT datatype in Sybase ASE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used string.Replace to replace the single (') quotes with double single quotes ('').

This escapes the single quotes when creating the Sybase SQL query.